# What is the point of the process fork creates being a copy of the parent?

Tags: c++, c, fork

I know the answer to "why is it this way" is because the language was invented so, but it seems like a lot of wasted effort that `fork()` spawns a copy of the process that called it. Perhaps it is useful sometimes, but surely the majority of time someone wants to start a new process its not to be a duplicate of the calling one? Why does fork create an identical process and not an empty one or one defined by passing an argument?

From [yolinux](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html)

> The fork() system call will spawn a new child process which is an
>   identical process to the parent except that has a new system process
>   ID

In other words when is it useful to start with a copy of the parent process?

Comment: One obvious answer: Apache webserver. One parent "controlling" instance of apache forking off a number of children, where those children are the ones actually handling the http requests. Much cheaper to pay the startup cost ONCE for the parent process, and piggyback the child processes

Comment: What code would the new process run if it wasn't a copy of the parent?

Comment: @MarkRansom: several systems support a "spawn" call which asks the OS kernel to create a fresh process with a specified executable. For example, this is what CreateProcess on Windows does.

Comment: @nneonneo Keeping up with POSIX semantics, we should refer to the various `exec()` variants, that will replace the actual process' code space (rather than starting a new process as calls like `system()` would do).

Comment: @MarkRansom OTOH, often one just calls `exec` straight after forking.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what I was thinking is why doesn't `fork()` have an argument that would basically be used to call `exec()`, sort of the functionality of `fork()` should be built into `exec()`.

Comment: @Celeritas Well, the (POSIX) API just doesn't provide s.th. like this. It's easy to brew your own function behaving like this though. I believe it's reasonable to have these functionalities separated actually.

Answer (score 8):

One big advantage of having the parent process duplicated in the child is that it allows the parent program to make customizations to the child process' environment before executing it.  For example, the parent might want to read the child process' `stdout`, in which case it needs to set up the pipes in order to allow it to read that *before* execing the new program.

It's also not as bad as it sounds, efficiency wise.  The whole thing is implemented on Linux using copy-on-write semantics for the process' memory (except in the special cases noted in the man page):

> Under Linux (and in most unices since version 7, parent of all unices alive now), fork() is implemented using copy-on-write pages, so the  only
>   penalty  that  it  incurs is the time and memory required to duplicate the
>   parent's page tables (which can be also copy-on-write), and to create a unique task structure for the child.

Comment: The performance hit should not be underestimated though, that's why there's `vfork()`.

Comment: `vfork()` does exist, but I can't think of a good reason to use it (especially after you read the `BUGS` section of the man page on linux).

Comment: vfork is basically useless. It is too restricted and too platform specific. fork works pretty darn well on Linux; if you really need the speed, clone is much less buggy than vfork.

Comment: This answer doesn’t really explain the motivation or necessity to me. Couldn’t a parent process have modified the child’s environment without the child using the parents executable?

Answer (score 6):

There are some very legitimate uses of the `fork` system call. Here are a few examples:

- Memory saving. Because `fork` on any modern UNIX/Linux system shares memory between the child and parent (via copy-on-write semantics), a parent process can load some static data which can be instantly shared to a child process. The `zygote` process on Android does this: it preloads the Java (Dalvik) runtime and many classes, then simply forks to create new application processes on demand (which inherit a copy of the parent's runtime and loaded classes).
- Time saving. A process can perform some expensive initialization procedure (such as Apache loading configuration files and modules), then `fork` off workers to perform tasks which use the preloaded initialization data.
- Arbitrary process customization. On systems that have direct process creation methods (e.g. Windows with [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), QNX with [spawn](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/s/spawn.html), etc., these direct process creation APIs tend to be very complex since every possible customization of the process has to be specified in the function call itself. By contrast, with `fork/exec`, a process can just fork, perform customizations via standard system calls (`close`, `signal`, `dup`, etc.) and then `exec` when it's ready. `fork/exec` is consequently one of the simplest process creation APIs in existence, yet simultaneously one of the most powerful and flexible.

To be fair, `fork` also has its fair share of problems. For example, it doesn't play nice with multithreaded programs: only one thread is created in the new process, and locks are not correctly closed (leading to the necessity of `atfork` handlers to reset lock states across a `fork`).

Comment: There is a school of thought that threads are evil. This implies that the mentioned problems are not fork's problems, but those of threads.

Comment: In a system with cheap process creation via cloning, threads are unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to all expectations, it's mainly `fork` that makes process creation so incredibly fast on Unices.

AFAIK, on Linux, the actual process memory is not copied upon fork, the child starts with the same virtual memory mapping as the parent, and pages are copied only where and when the child makes changes. The majority of pages are read-only code anyway, so they are never copied. This is called `copy-on-write`.

Use cases where copying the parent process is useful:

1. Shells

When you say `cat foo >bar`, the shell forks, and in the child process (still the shell) prepares the redirection, and then execs `cat foo`. The executed program runs under the same PID as the child shell and inherits all open file descriptors. You would not believe how easy it is to write a basic Unix shell.

2. Daemons (services)

Daemons run in the background. Many of them fork after some initial preparation, the parent exits, and the child detaches from the terminal and remains running in the background.

3. Network servers

Many networking daemons have to handle multiple connections at the same time. Example sshd. The main daemon runs as root and listens for new connections on port 22. When a new connection comes in it forks a child. The child just keeps the new socket representing that connection, authenticates the user, drops privileges and so on.

4. Etc

Answer (score 4):

Why `fork()`? It had nothing to do with C. C was itself only coming into existence at the time. It's because of the way the original UNIX memory page and process management worked, it was trivial to cause a process to be paged out, and then paged back in at a different location, without unloading the first copy of the process.

In *The Evolution of the Unix Time-sharing System* (http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/hist.html), Dennis Ritchie  says "*In fact, the PDP-7's fork call required precisely 27 lines of assembly code.*" See the link for more.

Threads are evil. With threads, you essentially have a number of processes all with access to the same memory space, which can dance all over each others' values. There's no memory protection at all.  See *The Art of Unix Programming*, Chapter 7 (http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch07s03.html#id2923889) for a fuller explanation.

Comment: +1, this is the answer to the original question: Why it was designed in this way.

Comment: Plus one for the historical reference (but not for maligning threads )